# Homebrew/Node.js showing up though not installed

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

When I do `find . -name "node*"` from my root directory, I get:

```
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node_exporter.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/nodeenv.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node-sass.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node@14.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node@10.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/nodebrew.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node@12.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/nodenv.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node@16.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node-build.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/node@18.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/nodejs
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/node@19
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Aliases/node.js
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/nodeclipse.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask/Casks/nodebox.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/rubocops/cask/extend/node.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/test/language/node_spec.rb
./usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/language/node.rb
```

but `brew ls` doesn't show node and `node -v` and `npm` show that the commands are not installed on PATH? What's going on here?

I went through the process of

I went through the process of removing all traces of Node and npm from my own installation as npm was corrupted (was mishandling vulnerabilities), and now want to install it using brew, or in some other way so all the errors with npm when attempting to `npm install` don't occur. Why does brew have node installed even though I didn't install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are not NodeJS itself, but are the instructions that tell Homebrew how to install NodeJS. You can remove those formula (along with any others that are not being used) with `brew cleanup`.

Edit: You cannot actually remove the formulae since those are needed if you were to install it at a later point.

Comment: They are still there with `cleanup`, probably for the reason you mentioned. Thanks for explaining it though

Comment: Yeah, cleanup won't remove the formula definitions, otherwise you wouldn't be able to install that software any more.